# Compare xml files

Tags: c#

I have a C# windows application,where in i am trying to compare the contents of the xml.
The based on the difference in the xml documents i have further processing .Is there an inbuilt API which compares the xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft XML Diff & Patch tool has the API for this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jay ,i think this will be usefull.Saw the APIs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe no one uses XML anymore, but I needed to create some code tonight that performs a comparison between two xml snippets that doesn't care about element order unless the elements are repeated (a contained list).  For a contained list, I do want to ensure the elements remain in their original order -- to ensure some form of unexpected sorting wasn't performed on its contents.

```
public static class XmlCompare
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Compares xml docs without regard to element order, unless the elements are a nested list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="primary">Any valid xml</param>
    /// <param name="secondary">Any valid xml</param>
    public static void Compare(string primary, string secondary)
    {
        Compare(XElement.Parse(primary), XElement.Parse(secondary));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Compares xml docs without regard to element order, unless the elements are a nested list
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="primary">Any valid xml</param>
    /// <param name="secondary">Any valid xml</param>
    public static void Compare(XElement primary, XElement secondary)
    {
        // iterate attributes found in primary; compare values
        foreach (XAttribute primaryAttribute in primary.Attributes())
        {
            var secondaryAttribute = secondary.Attribute(primaryAttribute.Name.LocalName);
            if (secondaryAttribute == null)
            {
                throw new Exception($"Element '{primary.Name.LocalName}' attribute '{primaryAttribute.Name.LocalName}' missing from secondary xml");
            }
            else
            {
                var primaryValue = primaryAttribute.Value;
                var secondaryValue = secondaryAttribute.Value;
                if (primaryValue != secondaryValue)
                    throw new Exception($"Element '{primary.Name.LocalName}' attribute '{primaryAttribute.Name.LocalName}' has an unequal value.  Expected '{primaryValue}', actual '{secondaryValue}'");
            }
        }

        // iterate attributes found in secondary; just ensure all attributes found in the secondary exist in the primary
        foreach (var secondaryAttribute in secondary.Attributes())
        {
            if (primary.Attribute(secondaryAttribute.Name.LocalName) == null)
                throw new Exception($"Element '{secondary.Name.LocalName}' attribute '{secondaryAttribute.Name.LocalName}' missing from primary xml");
        }

        // iterate elements of primary; compare values
        for (var i = 0; i < primary.Elements().Count(); i++)
        {
            var primaryElement = primary.Elements().Skip(i).Take(1).Single();
            var elementOccursMultipleTimes = primary.Elements(primaryElement.Name.LocalName).Count() > 1;
            if (elementOccursMultipleTimes)
            {
                // this comparison fails if the sequence of element entries has been altered between the primary
                // and secondary document, such as sorting a list by name in one document, but sorting by date
                // in the other.
                var secondaryElement = secondary.Elements().Skip(i).Take(1).SingleOrDefault();
                if (secondaryElement == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Element '{primaryElement.Name.LocalName}' missing from secondary xml");
                }

                Compare(primaryElement, secondaryElement);
            }
            else
            {
                var secondaryElement = secondary.Element(primaryElement.Name.LocalName);
                if (secondaryElement == null)
                    throw new Exception($"Element '{primaryElement.Name.LocalName}' missing from secondary xml");
                // to understand recursion, we must first understand recursion
                Compare(primaryElement, secondaryElement);
            }
        }

        // iterate elements of secondary; just ensure all the elements found in the secondary exist in the primary
        foreach (var secondaryElement in secondary.Elements())
        {
            if (primary.Element(secondaryElement.Name.LocalName) == null)
                throw new Exception($"Element '{secondaryElement.Name.LocalName}' missing from primary xml");
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but you could  deserialise the 2 xml fragments and do an object  over them.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question,i wanted an API.

Comment: why are you so much gung-ho about API.I think the code which does your job is fine.

Comment: dear Srinivas Reddy Thatiparthy
you are trying to create an argument here,what i am looking for is an API itself.If i were to write those implementations then this question would not have been in first place.